# package org.python.util does not exist

Tags: java, classpath, embed, package, jython

another problem. I have already placed my Jython.jar into what my computer recognizes as the Java CLASSPATH. This done, importing anything from Org.Python is not found by the compiler! Do I need to have the Jar in the same folder as the java code as well?

Thanks to anyone who replies :D

---------------------------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------------------

Still not working

within CLASSPATH I have Jython.jar.
within the location of my code and batch-compiler, I have the jar.
and I have typed "import org.python.util.*;" and nothing else are the beginning of my code

and it is still giving me errors :C

Comment: Are you getting errors at compile- or runtime? What are the commands you are using? What are the exact messages?

Comment: here is my batch compiler:
@echo off
javac *.java
echo done
    pause

Comment: [Errors on Compiler]                    as far as errors go: I get  (PythonScript.java:2: package org.python.util does not exist
import org.python.util.*;
^
1 error
done
)

Comment: I have one java file with Main. It creates an object (what I'm testing the script with)

Comment: Try compiling with the `-classpath` option pointing to the directory containing the JAR file as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: thanks. However I did as you said, I still have the same problem

Comment: javac -classpath C:\jython.2.7a2\jython.jar *.java
PythonScript.java:2: package org.python.util does not exist
import org.python.util.*;
^
1 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you spelled the package correctly! In java the convention is to have packages with small letters: `org.python`

If you are using command line to compile and run your code then you will need to add the folder containing the given `Jyhton.jar` file.

For more help take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html

If you are using an IDE:

**Eclipse:**

Got the `Properties/Java Build Path/Libraries`. From there you can add external Jars.

**Netbeans:**

Go to the projects `Properties/Libraries/Compile` tab and add all the JARs that you want to be included.

Comment: okay, thanks: ill try. I'm using nothin but the console and Notepad++

Comment: @hpityu, in **Netbeans** the path is :```Properties/Libraries/Compile``` tab